# location update in Single app mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mdm

I am working on an **enterprise application**. So from that, I am applying a profile for ***Single app mode*** that is working fine.

So my question is suppose I am allowing a calculator for Single app mode via MDM console and if my device moves from one place to another. That time, will **Apple iOS** allow fetching **Location** in the background?

[docs.simplemdm.com/article/35-location-tracking](https://docs.simplemdm.com/article/35-location-tracking) based on the last question answer they are saying not possible but I did not get any official doc regarding this from Apple

[discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250699830)

Comment: The link you posted doesn't clarify your question or add additional info, it just links to this exact same question on the Apple forums.  Unless there's a good reason to add it here, I would recommend removing it because it's not helping to provide a better question.

Comment: @fsb I added that because I posted there also for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, if you have **Geo Fencing** and **Locating tracking** enabled from your MDM, then your Single App mode or Kiosk option allows you to fetch the location from the background.

Just make sure the correct profile of MDM is installed on it with appropriate policy.

Comment: location tracking is working fine except **Single app mode**

Comment: https://docs.simplemdm.com/article/35-location-tracking
 based on the last question answer they are saying not possible but I did not get any official doc regarding this from **Apple**